# How can i add packages to alpine netboot

Tags: qemu, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I have download Alpine netboot distribution from this URL:

> https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/releases/x86/alpine-netboot-3.16.1-x86.tar.gz

I have run a virtual machine with QEMU this way:

```
qemu-system-i386 -m 256 -kernel boot/vmlinuz-lts -initrd boot/initramfs-lts -append "console=ttyS0 ip=dhcp alpine_repo=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/"
```

With this command, a virtual machine is created and 22 apk pacakges are installed.

I am able to install additionnal apk packages, but I have to do it by hand (`apk add` command).

How can I script packages installation in QEMU command line ?

Please note: I can replace http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/ by a local mirror. So, I can also change files on the repository.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271647/is-it-possible-to-script-qemu