# Automatically enter SSH password with script

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, openssh

I need to create a script that automatically inputs a password to OpenSSH `ssh` client.

Let's say I need to SSH into `myname@somehost` with the password `a1234b`.

I've already tried...

```
#~/bin/myssh.sh
ssh myname@somehost
a1234b
```

...but this does not work.

How can I get this functionality into a script?

Answer (score 349):

First you need to install [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/).

- Ubuntu/Debian: `apt-get install sshpass`
- Fedora/CentOS: `yum install sshpass`
- Arch: `pacman -S sshpass`

---

**Example:**

```
sshpass -p "YOUR_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no YOUR_USERNAME@SOME_SITE.COM
```

**Custom port example:**

```
sshpass -p "YOUR_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no YOUR_USERNAME@SOME_SITE.COM:2400
```

**Notes:**

- `sshpass` can also read a password from a file when the `-f` flag is passed.

  - Using `-f` prevents the password from being visible if the `ps` command is executed.
  - The file that the password is stored in should have secure permissions.

Comment: just be aware that while sshpass blocks your password from commands like `ps -aux`, you shouldn't normally run commands by typing your password because other users on the same computer may be able to see the password by running `ps -aux`.

if practical, you also want to use public key authentication instead, as mentioned in the other answer.  this allows you to separate authentication info from your script so you can share your script with others worry-free, and later decide to enable encryption on your ~/.ssh folder without also encrypting your script.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me on a server with a custom ssh port...why can't ssh just give us the option to insert the password in the command line?

Comment: Is there something equivalent for `cryptsetup luksAddKey /path/to/key`, which prompts `Enter a passphrase:` ?

Comment: for custom port to work add "-p port-number" at the end of command

Comment: Worth noting that there's still [a brief window of time](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88665/how-does-ps-know-to-hide-passwords) during which the password can be nabbed from `/proc`. It's still better to *not* use `sshpass` in this way. If possible, you want to pass passwords via files with strong permissions or (better yet) environment variables.

Comment: @abbotto How to do this with `ssh-add` instead of `ssh`, in order to add a key?

Comment: I've added an [answer with a more secure usage of `sshpass`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47397387/2063546).

Comment: Good enough solution for Jenkins pipelines.

Comment: `sshpass` has an option, `-f`, to read the password from a file. Thus, it won't be visible when using `ps`, and if the file has appropriate permissions in one's own home directory, it should be safe.

Comment: @Per Mejdal Rasmussen maybe its better than using `expect` but as long that you don't know what is the exact situation of the OP, you cannot state that as a fact. Not everyone is living in the same environment as you are used to. For my use case expect is the solution, all the other 'better' solutions won't work in my case.

Comment: Not available on Windows git bash

Comment: why we need to pass StrictHostKeyChecking=no

Comment: Mac OS is fun: trying `brew install sshpass` and got "Error: No available formula with the name "sshpass". **We won't add sshpass because it makes it too easy for novice SSH users to ruin SSH's security.**"

Comment: @Vladmir
For Mac OS you could try installing the unofficial package.
`https://gist.github.com/arunoda/7790979#installing-with-homebrew`

Comment: I tried  `sshpass -p "nvidia" ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no nvidia@"$x" "kill \`pgrep ads2\`" `. However it didn't work. ??

Comment: ssshpass work well on scp too

Answer (score 183):

After looking for an answer to the question for months, I finally found a better solution: writing a simple script.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

set cmd [lrange $argv 1 end]
set password [lindex $argv 0]

eval spawn $cmd
expect "password:"
send "$password\r";
interact
```

Put it to `/usr/bin/exp`, So you can use:

- `exp <password> ssh <anything>`
- `exp <password> scp <anysrc> <anydst>`

Done!

Comment: This answer should get more votes imo, it is a great wrapper. Just tried a few common operations like rsyncing with various flags and remote command execution and it worked every time. Added to my toolbox of useful scripts, Thanks @damn_c!

Comment: I used this to get around having to type in a password every time I ran an Ansible script on a new server instance that did not yet have my key in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. `exp <password> ansible-playbook set-user-remove-password-login.yml -k` To my great pleasure, the password was typed in when ansible prompted me with the *SSH password:*

Comment: The reason why this is IMO not a very good answer is because the password is written in the script which is by far the least secure method...

Comment: @PierreE the password is specified on the command line, not in the script.

Comment: The password will be visible by anyone who runs ps on the machine.

Comment: Lets say you entered the wrong password using this script. Then Terminal will ask for another password a few times before your script can continue. Is there some way the script can abort entering a password if it was not correct?

Comment: This is an extremely useful solution for non-standard ssh servers which don't work with `sshpass`

Comment: i've added `log_user 0` to skip some unrequired logs

Comment: This answer is the best way, simple but malleable. Keep in mind you'll need to install the expect package first. Also I don't see the purpose of the timeout at the start...

Comment: This solution has a downside:  It will break if you use SSH control sockets.  In this case, you are only asked for the password if you don't already have an active connection to the server.  If that connection is already there, then this expect script will sit waiting for the password prompt.  IMO `sshpass` is a better solution for this reason alone.

Answer (score 83):

Use public key authentication: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

In the source host run this only once:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa # ENTER to every field
ssh-copy-id myname@somehost
```

That's all, after that you'll be able to do ssh without password.

Comment: I see. But I am REQUIRED to ssh with password. This is because, "I" may have the script on a thumb drive and need to run it from any computer; while not disabling the need for password.

Comment: You can also store the private key on the said thumb drive.

Comment: @user1467855, I think you need to better explain your requirements.  Nobody is suggesting that you have an unsecure network.  In the public-key approach, it would still be possible for users to log in with the password.  But you would copy the private key onto your thumb drive, which means the thumb drive would be the only thing that can log in without a password.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am in OP situation, because the sysadmin disallows authentication by rsa/dsa keys and requires passwors. What are you gonna do.

Comment: I agree with @KarelBílek. The other options requires more skill, Python coding, expect. There is no easy option I think.

Comment: While I would normally COMPLETELY agree about using keyauth, my school's IT department is dumb and doesn't have keyauth enabled on their servers.

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating "ssh-copy-id". I was adding the IDs with the cumbersome way cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@host "cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys". This is so much easier!

Comment: A quick note to anyone who found this question from Googling like I did: Try this first, if you run into some sort of signing error, try using `ssh-add` on your machine. That fixed my issue.

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't even try to answer the actual question asked.

Comment: This still prompts for the first login and cannot be used in a script!

Comment: Using passwordless keys (you didn't even mention that is what happens when just pressing enter in response to all prompts) has the disadvantage that a major source of security leaks is accidentally backing up and exporting unencrypted key files.  Obviously sometimes some critical files have to live unencrypted - one way to handle that is keep those under etc and back etc up separately from main backup.

Comment: I am trying now to get this working since 10-12 hours. No luck: For another user its working but not for the one I need. Is there any solution on providing a pass in a script?

Answer (score 33):

You could use an expects script.  I have not written one in quite some time but it should look like below.  You will need to head the script with `#!/usr/bin/expect`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh HOSTNAME
expect "login:" 
send "username\r"
expect "Password:"
send "password\r"
interact
```

Comment: I did as you suggested but get the following errors: `/bin/myssh.sh: 2: spawn: not found
/bin/myssh.sh: 3: expect: not found
/bin/myssh.sh: 4: send: not found
/bin/myssh.sh: 5: expect: not found
/bin/myssh.sh: 6: send: not found`

Comment: Thanks Aaron for modifying my answer to be correct.  You may need to run the below command to find the correct path to put in for expect.`which expect`

Comment: You can also use this shebang line: `#!/usr/bin/env expect`

Comment: I added `interact` to the end so the ssh session is actually interactive

Comment: -1 for the huge security risk of keeping a plain text password in a script.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, how is this any less secure than any alternatives, for example the private key is also readable? Perhaps we should suggest that the script be readable only by the user?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Making the script only readable to a user makes it better. But root can still read it and most attackers try to get root access. Private keys are useless without passwords to unlock them. Which creates a loop since OP wanted to know how to avoid entering the password. But if he puts this script on a thumb drive, he's adding a lot of risk because thumb drives get lost or can be stolen and then, someone has access.

Answer (score 26):

Variant I

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh USER@SERVER
```

Variant II

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh USERNAME@SERVER "touch /home/user/ssh_example"
expect "assword:"
send "PASSWORD\r"
interact
```

Comment: No. sshpass is not ssh.

`SYNOPSIS
       sshpass [-ffilename|-dnum|-ppassword|-e] [options] command arguments`

Comment: In order to run sshpass in Linux CentOS you must `yum -y install epel-release` and then `yum -y install sshpass`

Comment: In this context of this data can be ignored

Comment: While I know this is an old post it's worth noting that the Variant II method would leave the password given to the session vulnerable in the bash history, making it highly inadvisable.

Answer (score 16):

### `sshpass` with better security

I stumbled on this thread while looking for a way to ssh into a bogged-down server -- it took over a minute to process the SSH connection attempt, and timed out before I could enter a password.  In this case, I wanted to be able to supply my password *immediately* when the prompt was available.

(And if it's not painfully clear: with a server in this state, it's far too late to set up a public key login.)

`sshpass` to the rescue.  However, there are better ways to go about this than `sshpass -p`.

My implementation skips directly to the interactive password prompt (no time wasted seeing if public key exchange can happen), and never reveals the password as plain text.

```
#!/bin/sh
# preempt-ssh.sh
# usage: same arguments that you'd pass to ssh normally
echo "You're going to run (with our additions) ssh $@"

# Read password interactively and save it to the environment
read -s -p "Password to use: " SSHPASS 
export SSHPASS

# have sshpass load the password from the environment, and skip public key auth
# all other args come directly from the input
sshpass -e ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive -o PubkeyAuthentication=no "$@"

# clear the exported variable containing the password
unset SSHPASS
```

Comment: note to self: update script to use `trap` to prevent ctrl-C from leaking the `SSHPASS` variable

Comment: I found that `PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive` didn't work, but replacing it with `PreferredAuthentications=password` worked.

Comment: I'm running `ssh` inside the remote machine again, with the same password.  Right now I'm exporting `SSHPASS` into the remote machine with `export SSHPASS=$SSHPASS`.  Is there a safer way?  To provide some context, I ssh into a cluster of machines, set up ssh keys, and then distribute them into other computers in the cluster. All of that runs from a script in a single computer.  So I need 2 levels of  `ssh`.

Comment: This solution is only for the case where you don't have prior access to the machine to set up a key-based login.  I would look at key forwarding https://dev.to/levivm/how-to-use-ssh-and-ssh-agent-forwarding-more-secure-ssh-2c32

Answer (score 16):

## sshpass + autossh

One nice bonus of the already-mentioned `sshpass` is that you can use it with `autossh`, eliminating even more of the interactive inefficiency.

```
sshpass -p mypassword autossh -M0 -t myusername@myserver.mydomain.com
```

This will allow autoreconnect if, e.g. your wifi is interrupted by closing your laptop.

#### With a jump host

```
sshpass -p `cat ~/.sshpass` autossh -M0 -Y -tt -J me@jumphost.mydomain.com:22223 -p 222 me@server.mydomain.com
```

Comment: Note that you can't add option `-f` to autossh in this combination, because `when used with autossh, ssh will be *unable* to ask for passwords or passphrases.` http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/README.txt also https://superuser.com/questions/1278583/autossh-not-working-in-background

Comment: This *seems* to work at first, but since the `-M0` flag disables monitoring my connection fails after a while without `autossh` realizing it; if I omit the flag then it also works until the connection fails, at which point my password is rejected by the server

Comment: Note that with this solution, anyone who logs into your system can see the password using `ps -ef` or some such command.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think I saw anyone suggest this and the OP just said "script" so...

I needed to solve the same problem and my most comfortable language is Python.

I used the paramiko library. Furthermore, I also needed to issue commands for which I would need escalated permissions using `sudo`. It turns out sudo can accept its password via stdin via the "-S" flag! See below:

```
import paramiko

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()

# To avoid an "unknown hosts" error. Solve this differently if you must...
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# This mechanism uses a private key.
pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(PKEY_PATH)

# This mechanism uses a password.
# Get it from cli args or a file or hard code it, whatever works best for you
password = "password"

ssh_client.connect(hostname="my.host.name.com",
                       username="username",
                       # Uncomment one of the following...
                       # password=password
                       # pkey=pkey
                       )

# do something restricted
# If you don't need escalated permissions, omit everything before "mkdir"
command = "echo {} | sudo -S mkdir /var/log/test_dir 2>/dev/null".format(password)

# In order to inspect the exit code
# you need go under paramiko's hood a bit
# rather than just using "ssh_client.exec_command()"
chan = ssh_client.get_transport().open_session()
chan.exec_command(command)

exit_status = chan.recv_exit_status()

if exit_status != 0:
    stderr = chan.recv_stderr(5000)

# Note that sudo's "-S" flag will send the password prompt to stderr
# so you will see that string here too, as well as the actual error.
# It was because of this behavior that we needed access to the exit code
# to assert success.

    logger.error("Uh oh")
    logger.error(stderr)
else:
    logger.info("Successful!")
```

Hope this helps someone. My use case was creating directories, sending and untarring files and starting programs on ~300 servers as a time. As such, automation was paramount. I tried `sshpass`, `expect`, and then came up with this.

Answer (score 8):

```
# create a file that echo's out your password .. you may need to get crazy with escape chars or for extra credit put ASCII in your password...
echo "echo YerPasswordhere" > /tmp/1
chmod 777 /tmp/1

# sets some vars for ssh to play nice with something to do with GUI but here we are using it to pass creds.
export SSH_ASKPASS="/tmp/1"
export DISPLAY=YOURDOINGITWRONG
setsid ssh root@owned.com -p 22
```

reference: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/youre-doing-wrong-ssh-plain-text-credentials-robert-mccurdy?trk=mp-reader-card

Comment: I think this article is just being sarcastic!

Comment: sarcastic maybe?  but this fine if trying to automate against systems with their default `admin` if you are in the process of provisioning them

Comment: No this does not require 'expect' or 'sshpass' ...  this being one of the ONLY ways to ssh with just native Debian install ... so this works without root @nhed

Also note 90% of these are just using non native programing, expect or sshpass all being the same 'answer' mine is the best ... so there ;P

Comment: I agree that it does not require `expect` / `sshpass`. 
@RmccurdyDOTcom didn't notice you linked your pwn article, so yeah you would know if you were sarcastic or not - but on that front I was referring to the prior comment by Yan.    Personally I would try to abstain from clear text and opt for ssh keys but there is the issue of bootstrapping virgin systems - where i think this is a good option if seeding the right public keys is not an option.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I login to my servers.

```
ssp <server_ip>
```

- alias ssp='/home/myuser/Documents/ssh_script.sh'
- cat /home/myuser/Documents/ssh_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p mypassword ssh root@$1
```

And therefore...

```
ssp server_ip
```

Comment: It seems all of your servers have same password

Comment: and the password is written in clear text in a script. Unsecure.

Answer (score 5):

I am using below solution but for that you have to install `sshpass` If its not already installed, install it using `sudo apt install sshpass`

Now you can do this,

`sshpass -p *YourPassword* ssh root@IP`

You can create a bash alias as well so that you don't have to run the whole command again and again.
Follow below steps

`cd ~`

`sudo nano .bash_profile`

at the end of the file add below code

`mymachine() { sshpass -p *YourPassword* ssh root@IP }`

`source .bash_profile`

Now just run `mymachine` command from terminal and you'll enter your machine without password prompt.

Note:

1. `mymachine` can be any command of your choice.
2. If security doesn't matter for you here in this task and you just want to automate the work you can use this method.

Comment: Note that `.bash_profile` is quite often word-readable. So putting your password there is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you @MartinPrikryl for addressing the issue, I have updated the note at the end so anyone who is using this solution, is also aware that password is easily readable.

Comment: Should **not** need `sudo` to edit _your own_ `.bash_profile`... :/

Answer (score 5):

This is basically an extension of abbotto's answer, with some additional steps (aimed at beginners) to make starting up your server, from your linux host, very easy:

> 1. Write a simple bash script, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p "YOUR_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <YOUR_USERNAME>@<SEVER_IP>
```

> 2. Save the file, e.g. 'startMyServer', then make the file executable by running this in your terminal:

```
sudo chmod +x startMyServer
```

> 3. Move the file to a folder which is in your 'PATH' variable (run 'echo $PATH' in your terminal to see those folders). So for example move it to '/usr/bin/'.

And voila, now you are able to get into your server by typing 'startMyServer' into your terminal.

P.S. (1) this is not very secure, look into ssh keys for better security.

P.S. (2) SMshrimant answer is quite similar and might be more elegant to some. But I personally prefer to work in bash scripts.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this on a Windows system, you can use Plink (part of PuTTY).

```
plink your_username@yourhost -pw your_password
```

Comment: For automatic script, don't forget the option "-no-antispoof" or the console will waiting with a message "Access granted. Press Return to begin session.". The command to be executed should be placed at the end: plink your_username@yourhost -pw your_password -no-antispoof your_command

Comment: The best answer for Windows user so far.

Comment: PuTTY have GUI options to store password, do not need cli anymore

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh USERNAME@SERVER "touch /home/user/ssh_example"
expect "assword:"
send "PASSWORD\r"
interact
```

**BUT**!!! If you have an error like below, just start your script with expect, but not bash, as shown here: `expect myssh.sh`
instead of `bash myssh.sh`

```
/bin/myssh.sh: 2: spawn: not found /bin/myssh.sh: 3: expect: not found /bin/myssh.sh: 4: send: not found /bin/myssh.sh: 5: expect: not found /bin/myssh.sh: 6: send: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working as follows

`.ssh/config` was modified to eliminate the yes/no prompt - I'm behind a firewall so I'm not worried about spoofed ssh keys

```
host *
     StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Create a response file for expect i.e. answer.expect

```
set timeout 20
set node [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh root@node service hadoop-hdfs-datanode restart

expect  "*?assword {
      send "password\r"   <- your password here.

interact
```

Create your bash script and just call expect in the file

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while [$i -lt 129]    # a few nodes here
  
  expect answer.expect hadoopslave$i

  i=[$i + 1]
  sleep 5

done
```

Gets 128 hadoop datanodes refreshed with new config - assuming you are using a NFS mount for the hadoop/conf files

Hope this helps someone - I'm a Windows numpty and this took me about 5 hours to figure out!

Comment: "I'm behind a firewall so I'm not worried about spoofed ssh keys". A firewall does exactly nothing in this case. The HostKeyCheck is so you can verify the host on the other end is not a trojan Host. I.e. one that's just pretending to be where you want to connect to. If you connect to an unknown host, and do something sensitive, like write a file that has credentials or a token or enter a password, that information is now effectively public knowledge. You being behind a firewall is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution that inclueds login with your account than changing to root user. 
It is a bash script

http://felipeferreira.net/index.php/2011/09/ssh-automatic-login/

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @abbotto did not work for me, had to do some things differently:

1. yum install sshpass changed to - *rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/sshpass-1.05-1.el6.x86_64.rpm*
2. the command to use sshpass changed to - *sshpass -p "pass" ssh user@mysite -p 2122*

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1**：use `sshpass`

```
#~/bin/myssh.sh
sshpass -p a1234b ssh myname@somehost
```

You can install by

```
# Ubuntu/Debian
$ sudo apt-get install sshpass

# Red Hat/Fedora/CentOS
$ sudo yum install sshpass

# Arch Linux
$ sudo pacman -S sshpass

#OS X
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb
```

or download the Source Code from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/), then

```
tar xvzf sshpass-1.08.tar.gz 
cd sshpass-1.08.tar.gz 
./configure
sudo make install
```

**Solution2**：Set SSH passwordless login

Let's say you need to SSH into `bbb@2.2.2.2(Remote server B)` with the password `2b2b2b` from `aaa@1.1.1.1(Client server A)`.

Generate the `public key(.ssh/id_rsa.pub)` and `private key(.ssh/id_rsa)` in A with the following commands

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
[Press enter key]
[Press enter key]
[Press enter key]
```

Use the following command to distribute the generated `public key(.ssh/id_rsa.pub)` to server B under bbb‘s .ssh directory as a file name `authorized_keys`

```
ssh-copy-id bbb@2.2.2.2
```

You need to enter a password for the first ssh login, and it will be logged in automatically in the future, no need to enter it again!

```
ssh bbb@2.2.2.2 [Enter]
2b2b2b
```

And then your script can be

```
#~/bin/myssh.sh
ssh myname@somehost
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get it working with that:

```
SSH_ASKPASS="echo \"my-pass-here\""
ssh -tt remotehost -l myusername
```

Answer (score -1):

In the example bellow I'll write the solution that I used:

The scenario: I want to copy file from a server using sh script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
$PASSWORD=password
my_script=$(expect -c "spawn scp userName@server-name:path/file.txt /home/Amine/Bureau/trash/test/
expect \"password:\"
send \"$PASSWORD\r\"
expect \"#\"
send \"exit \r\"
")

echo "$my_script"
```

Answer (score -1):

What i did here is

1. **ssh-keygen** - generate ssh key
2. copy the public key to the remote server. You can use **ssh-copy-id** or you can do it manually like this **cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@ip 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'**
3. Test it **ssh root@ip**

After that I add it on my **.zshrc** for easy use

```
sy-login(){
    ssh root@ip
}
```

**References**

https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/copy-id

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/beginners-guide-setting-ssh-linux-testing-setup/

Comment: This is what at least two existing answers how already (and technically, it's not an answer to the question, at least not without some explanation).

Answer (score -3):

Use this script tossh within script, First argument is the hostname and second will be the password.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set pass [lindex $argv 1]
set host [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh -t root@$host echo Hello
expect "*assword: " 
send "$pass\n";
interact"
```

Comment: What does this show on top of the existing answers? Particularly those by damn_c, Lipongo or RemiZOffAlex and others...

Comment: script execution along with ssh

     #!/usr/bin/expect
     set pass [lindex $argv 1]
     set host [lindex $argv 0]
     spawn ssh -t root@$host  sh /tmp/anyscript.sh
     expect "*assword: " 
     send "$pass\n";
     interact"

Answer (score -4):

To connect remote machine through shell scripts , use below command:

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USERNAME@IPADDRESS
```

where `IPADDRESS`, `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` are input values which need to provide in script, or if we want to provide in runtime use "read" command.

Comment: What does this answer show on top of existing answers? + Never ever suggest anyone to use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` without explaining the consequences.

Answer (score -4):

This should help in most of the cases (you need to install sshpass first!):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
read -p 'Enter Your Username: ' UserName;
read -p 'Enter Your Password: ' Password;
read -p 'Enter Your Domain Name: ' Domain;

sshpass -p "$Password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $UserName@$Domain
```

Comment: What does this show what other existing answers don't already? + Never suggest anyone to use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` without explaining the security consequences.

Comment: I do not see any *"quick and dirty"* in the OP.

Answer (score -21):

In linux/ubuntu

```
ssh username@server_ip_address -p port_number
```

Press enter and then enter your server password

if you are not a root user then add *sudo* in starting of command