# How to ignore responses in shell terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, centos

I am using CentOS 6.3.

How can I ignore or write 'y' when the terminal prompts a question?

For example, when I run 'yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk', it prompts me with this statement

```
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Is there anyway I could ignore or always say yes to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of yum it takes an option `-y` that answers yes to all questions asked.

```
yum -y install java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

For other installations you can try to pipe the command `yes` to the process but I'm not sure it would work with every program. Try it first.

```
yes | yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `Spawn`.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk
expect "[y/N]:" 
send "y\r"
interact
```

I'm not tested but I found "auto-terminal" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202587/ssh-script-that-automatically-enters-password/12202702#12202702)