# Passing a variable into bash command using python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, automation

I'm creating a small script and I'd like to pass a varable into a bash command using the python programming language, so for example:

```
number = raw_input("digit: ")
```

then i'd like to take the number variable and put it in bash command so for example:

```
ssh 'foo%s.bar'(number) <- where the %s is located id like it be replaced with the input
```

Finally I'd like to take that and run it in a bash command still within the python script:

```
ssh foo45.bar
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import subprocess
number = raw_input("digit: ")
subprocess.call(('ssh', 'foo{}.bar'.format(number)))
```

For some good reading, try the python docs for [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and for [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

If you want to integrate the above with sshpass, replace the subprocess call with:

```
subprocess.call(('sshpass', '-p', 'YOUR_PASSWORD', 'ssh', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', 'foo{}.bar'.format(number)))
```

Comment: @secure_20 Did this answer your question?  Or, was there other information that you were looking for?

Comment: it kinda answered my question but it's asking me to enter password. I'd like that to be passed in automatically as well @John1024

Comment: That question has been asked elsewhere on Stackoverflow: see [Automatically Enter SSH Password With Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202587/automatically-enter-ssh-password-with-script).

Comment: @secure_20  I just updated the answer with info for the sshpass solution.  If you can use public key authentication (as described in diegows' answer to that question, then I would recommend that instead.