# Connect to multiple ssh connections through scripts

Tags: bash, shell

I have been trying to automatically enter a ssh connection using a script. [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202587/automatically-enter-ssh-password-with-script) previous SOF post has helped me so far. Using one connection works (the first `ssh` statement). However, I want to create another ssh connection once connected, which I thought could look like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
# My ssh script

sshpass -p "MY_PASSWORD1" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no *my_hostname_1*
sshpass -p "MY_PASSWORD2" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no *my_hostname_2*
```

When running the script, I get only connected to the `my_hostname_1` and the second `ssh` command is not run until I exit the first `ssh` connection.

I've tried using an `if` statement like this:

```
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = my_host_name_1 ]; then
    sshpass -p "MY_PASSWORD2" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no *my_hostname_2*
fi
```

but I can't get any commands to be read until I exit the first connection.

Comment: I mean, how is it supposed to work? You can't have two active SSH sessions in the same window (despite e.g. by splitting the pane). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: if you're hoping to send the same cmd (at the same time) to multiple computers, this is not the solution. (There is a sysadmin program that will do this, but I can't find the name right now). Otherwise, read up about running shell cmds in the background with the `&` char at the end of a cmd-line. Good luck.

Comment: @TimZimmermann: he probably wants to use the first host as a gateway to the second.

Comment: @TimZimmermann The my_hostname_2 is only accessible throught my_hostname_1. Without a script I would run the first `ssh` command to connect to my_hostname_1, then run the second `ssh` command to connect to my_hostname_2. I thought I'd write a script in order to save time.

Comment: check ProxyCommand directive in ssh_config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a ProxyCommand example as suggested by @lihao:

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p "MY_PASSWORD2" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -o ProxyCommand='sshpass -p "MY_PASSWORD1" ssh m_hostname_1 netcat -w 1 %h %p' \
    my_hostname_2
```

You are proxying through the first host to get to the second.  This assumes you have `netcat` installed on `my_hostname_2`.  If not, you'll need to install it.

You can also set this up in your `~/.ssh/config` file so you don't need the proxy stuff on the command line:

```
Host my_hostname_1
    HostName my_hostname_1

Host my_hostname_2
    HostName my_hostname_2
    ProxyCommand ssh my_hostname_1 netcat -w 1 %h %p
```

However, this is a little trickier with the password handling. While you could put the `sshpass` here, it's not a great idea to have passwords in plain text. Using key based authentication might be better.

Comment: With the latest versions of `ssh` you can avoid calling `netcat`: `ProxyCommand ssh my_hostname_1 -W %h:%p` (it requires tunnels enabled on the gateway, through).

Answer (score 0):

A Bash script is a sequence of commands.

```
echo moo
echo bar
```

will run `echo moo` and wait for it to complete, then run the next command.

You can run a remote command like this:

```
ssh remote echo moo
```

which will connect to `remote`, run the command, and exit. If there are additional commands in the script file after this, the shell which is executing these commands will continue with the next one, obviously on the host where you started the script.

To connect to one host from another, you could in principle do

```
ssh host1 ssh host2
```

but the proxy command suggested by @zerodiff improves on several aspects of the experience.