# Go through multiple ssh connections and commands

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, automation, alias

My problem is a bit similar to one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643637/connect-to-multiple-ssh-connections-through-scripts), but *not the same*. *I cannot use sudo on external servers S1 / S2 / S3 (to install packages for example) unless they are binaries*.

### Each day I log onto the terminal locally, and run:

1. type/run initialization command **C1** locally
2. connect to server **S1** by ssh using **alias1** (from .bashrc **locally**)
3. connect to server **S2** from **S1** using **alias2** (from .bashrc in **S1**)
4. connect to server **S3** from **S2** using **alias3** (...)
5. type/run initialization command **C2** in **S3**
6. run "byobu" in **S3**, and then I do normal work in byobu.

I want to have a script, which does all those steps and leaves the terminal with byobu opened, cause I feel it is stupid, to type all those commands every day, but don't know how to change it :)

my try:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -C2qtnN -D1001 S1 & #C1 which is tunel for the browser
ssh S1
ssh S2 # here it fails, trying to execute "ssh S2" locally
ssh S3 # same as above
C2 # initialization command that has to be run before byobu on S3
byobu #this one wont work either - to open byobu ;S
```

Comment: Can you please show us what code you have written already and how it fails to do what you want?

Comment: sure, but it looks pathetic!

Comment: There are some good opportunities for learning some new skills here, but this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow which is for software development questions. You should consider asking it on [superuser](https://superuser.com) instead (or possibly https://unix.stackexchange.com). You probably want to read up on ssh jump hosts; one article is [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host) but there are many others.

Comment: You will need `HERE` docs - try the solution in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: The biggest thing you want to use is the `-J` option: `ssh -JS1,S2 S3 'C2 && byobu` should take care of all but the first line of your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a working solution:

The script **ssh_teleport.sh** looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -C2qtnN -D1001 S1 &                                                                                                                                                          
echo "tunnel ready!"                                                                                                                                                                                       
ssh -tt $1 'bash -l -c "C2"'
```

Where **$1 can be any host** from {S1, S2, S3}
and C2 is a full command(aliases, unfortunately, don't work) to run on ssh given in $1

In order to jump (thanks to @chepner) I had to modify config in .ssh on my local machine, the way it is described [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host):

```
Host S1
    HostName IP_of_S1
    User MyUsername1

Host S2
    HostName someHostname1
    User MyUsername2
    ProxyJump S1

Host S3
    HostName someHostname2
    ProxyJump S2
    User MyUsername3
```

The final touch is to **add an alias to .bashrc**:

```
alias teleportS3='./scripts/ssh_teleport.sh S3'
```

It does its purpose!