# Shell Script to access a remote machine using ssh with usr and pwd both

Tags: shell, ssh, scripting, remote-access, expect

I am writing a shell script that can connect to another remote machine and query the DB , write the result in a file and copy the file back to main machine.
I am facing issue while connecting to DB.
I am not understanding how to connect to the remote machine.
I am using ssh root@DB_IP the then ORACLE query. But its always asking a password.
How to provide both username and password while doing a ssh to the remote machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically Enter SSH Password With Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202587/automatically-enter-ssh-password-with-script)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two ways:-

1. By adding your **id.rsa.pub** in your remote machine (~/.ssh/authorized_keys)
2. `sshpass -p password ssh root@ip "sh run.sh "`