# ssh connect to user on another server and execute shell commands as that user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ssh

While I am connecting to another server using `ssh` I am using 'EOF' marker to execute some commands in remote server. But they are failing to execute commands on remote server.

Also when password-less `ssh` connectivity is not enabled, how to input password from the script without requiring the user to enter password?

```
$ su - oracle < passwd.txt
standard in must be a tty
```

Comment: Please add any error messages and actual commands executed (copy-and-paste, don't re-type).

Comment: added error I am getting while ssh connect to another server.

Comment: Consider using `sshpass` or `expect`. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27994731/1328439).

Comment: The error message says that with input redirect you cannot enter a password. If you solve the password issue by setting up passwordless authentication or using `sshpass` or `expect`, then document-here with EOF marker would work as expected.

Comment: yes but I am trying to do it this way. By saving the password in a file to which no one has access so that I can stay secure. I want to use this password file to login

Answer (score 0):

If password less conectivity is not enabled (assuming keys auth is enabled - much more secure..) then use keys between machines.. 
Generate keys using ssh-keygen and copy it to remote servers using ssh-copy-id

Comment: I am trying to do this without enabling password-less connectivity

Answer (score 0):

The good way to do it would be to setup a password-less sudo just for that command.

Install the `sudo` command if you don't have it, then modify the sudoers file with the `visudo` command, and add a line like that:

```
youruser    ALL=(oracle) NOPASSWD: the command you want to launch
```

For instance

```
girish    ALL=(oracle) NOPASSWD: /bin/stop-process
```

Then, in your script, just do:

```
ssh girish@myserver 'sudo -u oracle /bin/stop-process'
```

and no password will be asked.

Comment: Hi. I am aware of using this sample script with password less connectivity. But I am looking for a way to do this to keep the password in script or in a seperate file in OS. In our servers its a security measure to not enable password less connectivity for any commands.

Comment: Security is to not keep your password in plaintext in a script. Create a special user account that can do that, with an ssh-key, and you'll be as safe as possible.

Comment: In the example I shown, I kept the password in a text file which only the current user can open and only I know the location so its secure. I am trying to find a way to use that text file to login

Comment: And it's not a good idea. Please head to security.stackexchange.com for more information about how it is a very bad idea.