# Hiding output to command prompt for send command

Tags: shell, expect

I am using commands to connect to remote server using ssh

```
spawn ssh userId@host
expect "password:"
send "password\r"
```

Issue is sometime,even before shell prompt for password, send command is run which result's in password getting display in plain text on console.

It there a way to

1. make sure, send is always called after expect
2. or if it get's called, it should display something like `*******` and not plain text

I read the documentation of `send` but no luck there.

Comment: `sshpass -p "YOUR_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no YOUR_USERNAME@SOME_SITE.COM` ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202587/automatically-enter-ssh-password-with-script

Comment: If possible, use public-key authentication to login without a password, instead of exposing your password in a script (which both `sshpass` and `expect` do).

Comment: This is not in any way a `bash` question. `expect` is its own, TCL-based language -- when you're running expect, you're not in bash anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide output from console ussing `stty` or `log_user`.

Using `stty`

```
spawn ssh userId@host
expect "password:"
stty -echo
send "password\r"
stty echo
```

Using `log_user`

```
spawn ssh userId@host
expect "password:"
log_user 0
send "password\r"
log_user 1
```