# Specifying password in .ssh/config file?

Tags: ssh, openssh

Is it possible to specify password inside my .ssh/config file? Something like

```
Host host1
    User user1
    Pass password
```

All resources I found recommend to use keys instead, but that's not an option for me, I want to use password.

If it's not possible with stock openssh, are there any patches laying around that would allow this?

EDIT: reason I need to use password is to get access to network drives when connection to cygwin sshd from linux.

Comment: you could also look into using [`sshpass`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass)

Comment: @MattClark well tell that to windows. they won't unlock network drives unless you use password to log in. do I like it? no. do I have a choice? no.

Comment: @MattClark thanks for the tip, will look into it :)

Comment: You mention Windows network drives? I am confused as to your setup now, are the shares not via samba? Could you [edit] your post to provide some more details of your setup and use case?

Comment: I'm connecting from linux machine to windows machine where there is sshd via cygwin.. and while you can use ssh keys to login into such setup, the windows session then doesn't have access to network drives, you need to login using password to get that. I didn't think that it is relevant to my problem, since I need to specify password on linux machine, the fact that on the other end is cygwin should be irrelevant.. but will put it into my question :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically enter SSH password with script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202587/automatically-enter-ssh-password-with-script)

Answer (score 35):

No, it is not possible. The configuration options are described in the manual page for `ssh_config` and there is no such option as `Pass`.

There are no patches (at least I didn't see any during the years yet), because it is very insecure to store passwords in plain text. Using some obfuscated method will not make it any more secure and real encryption would add here a lot of complexity (and a new encryption passphrase).

Really, use the SSH keys. They are cool, secure and easy to use. Just two commands to set up and third to use.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
$ ssh-copy-id server
$ ssh server
```

Comment: I cannot use ssh keys, windows won't unlock network drives unless you use password to log in :/

Comment: I need this too, can't use ssh keys, because the other system is read-only (it's a home vacuum cleaner, so it's just for fun)

Comment: The solution works for me and this help me, `$ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/keyname username@hostip`

Comment: What is the difference between storing passwords in plain text with storing privet keys in plain text? How one can be very insecure but not the other?

Comment: @Peyman when you use SSH authentication you are sending the password over to the server. When you decrypt the private key locally, the passphrase is never leaving your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my ~/.bashrc

```
function ssh() {
  if [[ "$1" == "server1" ]]; then
    command sshpass -p 'PASSWORD1' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@SERVER1_IP
  elif [[ "$1" == "server2" ]]; then
      command sshpass -p 'PASSWORD2' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@SERVER2_IP
  elif [[ "$1" == "server3" ]]; then
      command sshpass -p 'PASSWORD3' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@SERVER3_IP
  else
    command ssh "$@"
  fi
}
```

This way it acts like you would ssh something in your config "ssh server1".