# Automatic enter input in shell command line

Tags: linux, bash, unix, input, command-line

I want to automatically input in a command line. I am using openshift command for this. So when i type `oc login https://....` it asks for username and password.

```
 $ oc login https://......
   Username:  (after putting and pressing enter, password is next)
   Password:
```

So i want to automatically login with just one command, I've seen many tutorials but the input is only yes or no. For example  `$ echo yes | script.sh` . But how about the situation above? Thanks.

Comment: You can also write an Expect script. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28293101/7285732) might help

Comment: $ oc login 10.x.x.x:8443 -u username -p password