# SSHLibrary prompts for password

Tags: python, robotframework, paramiko, robotframework-sshlibrary

I have a problem with a test suite. I use robot framework and python.I created a function in python which executes a console command in a remote Linux client.

```
def purge_default_dns(device_ip):
    ssh_val = "usr1@" + device_ip
    command = "ctool dns | grep -v \"grep\" | awk \'{print $2}\'"
    test = check_output(["ssh", ssh_val, "-p", "6022", command])
```

The `check_output()` function connects with `device_ip` and executes command. If I try to connect with a fully qualified domain name (ex. `my.domain.io`), then I get a prompt for password (which is empty). I press enter and command executes regular. Is there any parameter that passes for example Enter when password prompt comes up?
I tried `ssh -e` switch , I don't want to change ssh client , I just need a generic solution.

[image: Console windows]

---

For example using paramiko library in the code below , I can create an paramiko `SSHClient` , which has a parameter for password and doesn't prompt anything. While I can't use paramiko right now , I need something else with SSHLirary to go around the problem.

```
def send_ssh_command(device_ip , command):
    hostname = device_ip
    password = ""
    username = "usr1"
    port = 6022
    try:
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
        client.connect(hostname, port=port, username=username, password=password)
        stdin , stdout , stderr = client.exec_command(command)
        command_return_val = stdout.read()
    finally:
        client.close()
    return command_return_val
```

Thank you.

Comment: Given that the examples are all custom code, any reason why the Robot Framework SSH library doesn't work for you?

Comment: I am not familiar with it.However it might usefull for me.Good point!Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this straight, the only solution you look for is to pass the password on the command line to the default OS `ssh` client, and do not/cannot install any libraries (paramiko, etc) that can help you achieve the same result through other means?

I'm asking this, because the robot framework's [SSHLibrary](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html) provides this out of the box; you already have the python's solution with `paramiko`; and the general linux solution is to install the `sshpass` [package](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/), and use it to pass the value:

```
sshpass -p "YOUR_PASS" ssh -usr1@my.domain.io:6022
```

So if all of these are not an option, you are left with two alternatives - either hack something around `SSH_ASKPASS` - here's [an article](https://www.exratione.com/2014/08/bash-script-ssh-automation-without-a-password-prompt/) with a sample, or use `expect` to pass it - this one is what I'd prefer out of the two.

Here's a very good [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28293101/3446126) with an `expect` script wrapper around `ssh`.  In your method, you will have to first create a file with its content, set an executable flag on it, and then call that file in `check_output()`, passing as arguments the password, 'ssh' and all its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Why You need to go with python , I am using below code in robotframework for the same:

```
[Arguments]    ${host}=${APP_SERVER}    ${username}=${APP_USERNAME}    ${password}=${APP_PASSWORD}
Open Connection    ${host}    timeout=2m
Login    ${username}    ${password}
${out}  ${err}  ${rc}=   Execute Command   cd ${PATH};ctool dns | grep -v \"grep\" | awk \'{print $2}\' *    return_stdout=True   return_stderr=True   return_rc=True
Should Be Equal   ${rc}  ${0}
```