# Ansible raw module - how to handle the password prompt on SFTP/SCP?

Tags: ansible, sftp, scp, junos-automation

For an ansible playbook to copy over a file on a target **Junos** machine, I need the **raw** module and **sftp/scp** to use.

The target machine (Junos) *doesn't have python*, so I have only **raw** module on the ansible side to run commands. And I've been trying **sftp/scp** both require the *password* to be entered on the prompt, but not getting it working using **raw** module.

If the copy command could be done in a single line, that'd work too, but the target machine doesn't have **sshpass** too. So, I'd hope to get any workaround so *password* can be provided on the prompt from **raw** module of ansible playbook.

*This is from the Junos, sftp works fine after providing password on prompt.*

```
root@:~ # sftp <username>@host:/file/location/file destFile
<username>@host's password:
```

*And the playbook has the same command for **raw** but, can't handle the prompt for **password** even using multiple commands setting for **raw** using (;/&&).*

```
     - name: "Copy config file on Junos"
#       raw: sftp <username>@host:/file/location/file destFile && <password>
#       raw: sftp <username>@host:/file/location/file destFile;<password>
       raw: sftp <username>@host:/file/location/file destFile
       register: disp
     - name: "Print disp"
       debug:
         var: disp
```

In short, how can I manipulate using the **raw** module of ansible to allow providing the *password* on the prompt?

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Ansible raw module providing the password on the prompt."***

A: The module [*raw*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/raw_module.html) is not able to provide a password. You'll have to script it. See [*Automatically enter SSH password with script*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202587/automatically-enter-ssh-password-with-script)

---

```bash
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set cmd [lrange $argv 1 end]
set password [lindex $argv 0]
eval spawn $cmd
expect "password:"
send "$password\r";
interact
```

Put it to /usr/bin/exp, So you can use

```bash
shell> exp <password> sftp <anysrc> <anydst>
```

---

In Ansible, you can use the module [*expect*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html) and *`delegate_to: host`* if *host* can be used as an Ansible client. In this case, instead of pulling the file from *host* by *junos*, *host* can push the file to *junos*. Fit the *responses* to your needs

```yaml
- name: Copy config file on Junos
  expect:
    command: scp /file/location/file username@junos:destFile
    responses:
      (?i)username@junos's password: "MySekretPa$$word"
  delegate_to: host
```

---

Q: ***"I dont know why delegate_to: host was used."***

A: ***host*** here is either [*ansible_host, or inventory_hostname*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#connection-variables). The question says: *"from the Junos, sftp works fine"*

```bash
root@:~ # sftp <username>@host:/file/location/file destFile
<username>@host's password:
```

The question also says: *"The target machine (Junos) doesn't have python ... (in Ansible) can't handle the prompt for password"*. In this case, you can't run the module *expect* on *junos*. Instead, you have to **push** the file from *host* to *junos*, i.e to run the scp command on *host*

```yaml
- name: Copy config file on Junos
  expect:
    command: scp /file/location/file username@junos:destFile
    responses:
      (?i)username@junos's password: "MySekretPa$$word"
  delegate_to: host
```

This is the reason for *`delegate_to: host`* The questioner in his own answer writes: *"Here's the working .yml below"*

```yaml
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Copy config file on Junos
      expect:
        command: scp srcFile <user>@junos:/dest/file/
        responses:
          (.*)Password: "<password>"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Here the *`delegate_to: localhost`* is redundant because the task is running on *localhost* anyway. But, it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: But that's going to copy the file to the local host, rather than to the Junos device.

Comment: You're right. I missed the correct direction. Probably scp and *delegate_to: host* would do the job. I've fixed my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, that would've worked if the Junos had python in it.

Comment: @SaifAhmed: "*scp*" does not depent on "*python*". "*python*" is not needed at Junos to "*scp  destFile username@junos:/file/location/file*". Have you tried?

Comment: @VladimirBotka yes, that's true. But I didn't mean "scp"/"sftp", I referred to "expect" actually.

Comment: @SaifAhmed: "*expect*" is delegated to "*host*". Have you tried?

Comment: I dont know why `delegate_to: host` was used. I was able to accomplish this without using that line. It downloaded the files from another host to the remote host that was being used in the playbook with no problems. Using `delegate_to: host` failed for me.

Comment: @Dave, you're running the task on the host you want to if you don't need *delegate_to: host*. I added detailed explanation to the answer. I also fixed the confusing *src* and *dest* paths.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, there's no such example to handle password prompt with the **raw** module.

Thus, decided to do the whole thing differently like, using **expect** copy file from *Ansible host* to *junos*. Here's the working **.yml** below:

```yaml
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Copy config file on Junos
      expect:
        command: scp srcFile <user>@junos:/dest/file/
        responses:
          (.*)Password: "<password>"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: Here you don't need `delegate_to: localhost` because the play is running on the single host *localhost*.