# Linux - Pass password inside script shell

Tags: linux, shell, sshfs

I have trouble to pass a password automatically in my script. This is how it looks like when I do it manually:

```
sshfs -o nonempty user@sftp.server.com:/ /home/administrator/data
```

I am now forced to enter the password for `sshfs`:

```
password
```

I try to automate that in a script and pass the password like this to standard input:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "password" | sudo -S sshfs -o nonempty user@sftp.server.com:/ /home/administrator/data
```

When I run the script, I am still forced to enter the password. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [sshfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS) wiki it seems this is used to mount a remote file system.

This looks like more of a SSH issue really, if your ssh config is configured to use a password only then you'll get prompted. Its better (and more secure) to use a SSH key without a passphrase imo.

As per the wiki:

> SSH will ask for the password, if needed. If you do not want to type in the password multiple times a day, see [SSH keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys).

Comment: that does not help me, it is the way our IT has setup our system. They will not provide me the SSH Keys unfortunately. I know passing the password in a script works, I have seen this before

Comment: @DataMastery I found an interesting q/a here you might be able to use one of these but ymmv: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202587/automatically-enter-ssh-password-with-script