# Execute commands on remote server behind another server (jumphost) using Plink

Tags: ssh, putty, plink

I am trying to make an automation using Power Automate Desktop for PuTTY. I have come across a solution to use cmd to run commands using `plink`.
I used the following steps:

1. I added PuTTY to system variables
2. I used the command (in cmd):

   ```
   plink -ssh hostname@ipaddress -pw password -no-antispoof -m C:\commands.txt
   ```
3. I edited `command.txt`:

   ```
   ssh anotherIP -pw passwordForAnotherIP
   cd /tmp
   cat filename
   ```

When I run the command in cmd, I can not input password for the other server that needs to be accessed inside the first one. The error shown is

> Bad Port 'w'

The server runs bash 4.2. How can I input password inside the txt file commands so that command line `plink` command takes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better solution is using [Plink's `-proxycmd`](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-proxycmd):

```
plink -ssh anotherIP -pw passwordForAnotherIP -no-antispoof -proxycmd "plink -ssh hostname@ipaddress -pw password -nc anotherIP:22" -m C:\commands.txt
```

With the `commands.txt` containing only the:

```
cd /tmp
cat filename
```

---

To answer your literal question:

The OpenSSH `ssh` has no `-pw` switch. See [Automatically enter SSH password with script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12202587/850848).

Additionally, your `command.txt` won't do what you think anyway. It won't run the `cd` and `cat` within the `ssh`. It would run them *after* the `ssh`. So on the  `ipaddress`. How to do this properly is discussed in: [Entering password to remote ssh through Plink after establishing a connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73475044/850848).