# Transfer file from remote server behind another server (jumphost) to local machine using pscp

Tags: sftp, pscp

I am trying to transfer file from a remote server behind jumphost server to my local machine using `pscp` and SFTP. I know how to do it for a remote server but not for jumphost-ed server. Also I need to make it automated (no user interaction needed), how do I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the same way you already execute command over the jump host:
[Execute commands on remote server behind another server (jumphost) using Plink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68353129/850848)

Just use `pscp`, where you are using `plink`.

Something like this:

```
pscp -pw password2 -proxycmd "plink -ssh user1@jumphost -pw password1 -nc anotherIP:22" user2@example.com:/remote/path/file.txt .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxycommand:

```
scp -oProxyCommand = "ssh -W %h:%p username/password@jumphost" username/password@remotehost:/some/path/on/remote/host some/path/on/local/machine
```

Comment: Where do I add the username,ip and password for server 1(the main server to connect to) and server 2(the next server where I jump to)? I can only see 1 %h %p combination (if it means hostip and password)

Comment: I ran this command but it's showing missing argument. I ran  `scp -oProxyCommand = "ssh -W %h:%p username1/pass1@ip1" username2/"pass2"@ip2:\path\to\file\inside\server\file.csv C:\Users\Mayank\Desktop `  I used "" in pass2 because the pass had @ in it, so I thought i'd escape that. it ran same as without the "" and both time threw error `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` But I have access to it in gui putty using the same path

Comment: OpenSSH tools (`ssh`, `scp`, `sftp`) cannot accept password on their commands line.