# How to execute ssh connect by script?

Tags: powershell, ssh

I have local Windows 10 and remote Ubuntu server.

I want to automate connection to server and write executable script witch connects by ssh to server and open new terminal from another server.

**What it's supposed to look like**

I double click on bat

[image]

And then script

1. inits ssh connect
2. writes password
3. gives the user a terminal with a ready ssh connection.

That is, it mimics the following

[image]

**Problems**

1. How to wait ssh password request? All commands executes immediately.
2. (additional) can I write it in `.sh` script, run script, execute all in "start" terminal (from which I run `.sh` script) and then pass ssh control to invoked terminal?

It's best if someone writes a ready-made script

Answer (score 0):

[Automatically enter SSH password with script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202587/automatically-enter-ssh-password-with-script)

Answers:

1. Direct answer -  use `expects`. But `sshpass` is better. Also RSA-key can be used.
2. Can`t tell anything.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done without any 3rd party tools like this:

```
$env:TMPPW=Get-Content -Path 'secure_file.txt' ; $un='MyUserName'
$j=Start-Job -ScriptBlock{Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
(New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell).SendKeys("$env:TMPPW{ENTER}")}
& ssh.exe -q -4 -l $un 127.0.0.1 'whoami'
$env:TMPPW=([guid]::NewGuid()).Guid ; $env:TMPPW=$null
```