# How to expand a password variable when login to SSH with a Script

Tags: shell, ssh, iterm2

This is to follow up on this thread:
[Automatically enter SSH password with script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202587/automatically-enter-ssh-password-with-script)

In my case, i cannot use sshpass, i cannot use expect, I just need to script it as if no other packages are installed on the end user machine.

I want to ssh through a shell script and expand the password but it does not work.

So, using a shell script, let's say I create those variables:

```
_USER='Joebloe'
_MACHINE='1.1.1.1'
_PASSWORD='Password'
```

Then, the goal is just to ssh and pass the password:

```
ssh $(echo $_USER)@$(echo $_MACHINE)  ##That works fine
```

Then, it prompts for the password:

Joebloe Password:

But I cannot say echo $_PASSWORD or even $(echo $_PASSWORD) because it takes the values literally.

Is there a way to expand the password as soon as you type it, or before it is processed, or it is not doable through a shell script?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should set up public-key authentication, which does not require any additional software, just a one-time login with the password.

Comment: The fact that `ssh` only reads passwords from the terminal, not from a file or standard input, is a *feature*, to prevent password leaks.

Comment: `ssh`is reading a literal password directly, not via a shell that can process your input before `ssh` sees it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sshpass`, but this is a bad decision. It is better to use [key-based authorization.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server)

But if you are confident in your actions there is  example:

Install sshpass:

Debian-based (Ubuntu):
`$ apt-get install sshpass`

Fedora/CentOS:
`$ yum install sshpass`

Arch-based:
`$ pacman -S sshpass`

```
$ sshpass -p $(echo $_PASSWORD) ssh $(echo $_USER)@$(echo $_MACHINE)
```